# Multi Country and Language Site

Tags: i18n-l10n, multi-sites

I'm trying to build a single global website that houses multiple countries, each with their own set of language translations. There is also a global overview site that also has its own language options. The global site will live on global.domain.com and function the same as a country site, and the countries will be at domain.com/langcode-countrycode/ (domain.com/en-us/). From anywhere on any site, the user will have a menu to navigate to another country/language. There will only be a dozen countries or so. There will also be company sites, but they are identical to the country sites. Each country/company will have its own management team that should only be able to edit their section. Each also needs the option to swap the logo and maybe some colors, but that's it.

From what I've found, Domain Access and Organic Groups, coupled with i18n, seems like the best option, but I just can't seem to get it set up in the right way. Is there a better approach to that?

Some countries want to be able to use another domain to access their country site, which I'm guessing would just be an alias to the main domain in Domain Access.

I can mostly picture how I would build this in WordPress, or even from scratch, but I'm new to Drupal, so I might be missing something obvious...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need a multi-site Drupal installation and each of those sites needs something like organic groups and also i18n.

Unless I am misunderstanding... what you're describing only makes sense if all the content across all sites is the exact same,  just translated versions.

Comment: The majority of the content is going to be the same. The main company offers services in each country. Each country site will consist of a homepage, about (which will mostly be about the company in general), services, contact. The services will only vary slightly by country. Does that make sense? A multi-site installation seemed too separate, and difficult for the client to add to later. Also, it seemed like it wouldn't work well with the required URL structure...